# How can I find which column header is selected?

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a datagrid view in my form and I like to sort the table by clicking the columnheader.

I  choose the Columnheader DoubleClick Event for writing the code but I don't know, how I should tell which column header is selected.

Is there any way for it or I have to change my mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the DataGridView's [ColumnHeaderMouseClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick.aspx).

When the event fires you can get the index value of the clicked column through the event's DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs.ColumnIndex property.  The article I linked has an example.

Answer (score 2):

In both `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` and `OnColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` events you can do:

```
private void DataGridView1_OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    int column = e.ColumnIndex;
}
```